# Angular2 - Passing URL as route parameter

Tags: angular

I'm trying to find a working solution for passing a full URL as a parameter for one of routes in my Angular2 application.

Here is fragment of my app-routing.module.ts file :

```
const routes: Routes = [

{
    path : '',
    component : HomePageContentComponent
},
 {
    path : 'explore',
    component : ExploreRosFacetedSearchPageContentComponent
},
{
    path : 'explore/:keyword',
    component : ExploreRosFacetedSearchPageContentComponent
},
{
    path : 'rodetails',
    component : RoDetailsComponent
},
{
    path : 'rodetails',
    component : RoDetailsComponent,
    children : [
        {
        path : 'overview/:uri',
        component : OverviewComponent
        },
```

When I pass for example **localhost:4200/rodetails/overview/http://someadress.com** in my web browser, I want to execute my 'Overview' component with this parameter. The problem  is:  because URL in parameter is not encoded - Angular engine probably didn't know that it is actually a parameter because of **'/'** characters in it. It tries to find component with route path **overview/http/**  and it crashes with **Cannot GET /rodetails/overview/http://someaddress.com**

If someone has dealt with problems like this before or know how to handle this use case, I appreciate any insight very much.

Comment: Why not just use a query parameter `?url=http://someaddress.com`

Comment: Why not encoding the url and passing it via query parameter instead ?